# how to run asp.net core run and vue js serve in same command window?

Tags: batch-file, vue.js, asp.net-core, command-line

When I launch my asp.net core vue js app in debug it launches the whole thing in a single console window. I am writing a batch file to do all that for testing but I am having to open up two windows since after I do `dotnet run` it does not run any commands after it:

```
REM start asp.net core backend
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
cd C:\git\MyApp\MyApp.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\win-x64
dotnet MyApp.Web.dll --console --launch-profile MyApp.Web

REM the following is not run...
cd C:\git\MyApp\MyApp.Web\ClientApp
npm run serve
```

How can I run it in a single console window like VS does?

Comment: What is `dotnet`? an executable, or a batch file? if it is the latter, do `call dotnet ...` (same for `npm`). And change all `cd ...` to `cd /D ...`...

Comment: dotnet is an executable, its the program that launches a .net core app

Answer (score 0):

For `dotnet MyApp.Web.dll` and `npm run serve`, both command will block the command window process, the following command will not run until you terminate the previous task.

For a workaround, you need to start the `npm run serve` from Asp.Net Core.

For Asp.Net Core Angular template, there is built-in feature called `AngularCliMiddlewareExtensions`.

For vue client, you could follow [ASP.NET Core Vue CLI Templates](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-core/1500/aspnet-core-vuejs-template) to implement `VueDevelopmentServerMiddleware`.

Here is the source code [ASPCoreVueCLITemplates](https://github.com/DaniJG/ASPCoreVueCLITemplates)

Comment: Sure I understand that, and that is how it works from VS, but I want to do it from a batch file so that I can run my cypress tests after it starts.

Comment: @ColtonScottie What do you mean it works from VS? For this template, you could try `dotnet` command which will run `npm` command, there is no need to call the `npm` command by yourself..